# Swagger-PHP/Doctrine annotations, OpenAPI 3 and JSON:API format

Tags: openapi, json-api, swagger-php

Can anyone tell me if OpenApi 3 supports a JSON:API format? I have been looking around and can't really seem to figure out if it is supported. Currently I am using CakePHP 3.6 and Swagger-php/doctrine annotations to create OA3 documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is helpful: https://discuss.jsonapi.org/t/openapi-3-0-spec-that-conforms-to-json-api/1803 Haven't done it on my own so I'm not sure how good it is.